# Problems when adding social media shareing in my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, facebook-social-plugins

I am adding social media functions on my app and I want to be able to put my own image in the box on the right when the user shares it on their facebook.
I have attached the code I used below. How do I make it so I can add a image so it will be shown when the user posts it on their facebook?
Thanks in advance

```
@IBAction func facebook(_ sender: Any) 
{
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)  
    {
        let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        vc?.setInitialText("How many of these expressions can you relate to? http://www.example.com")
        vc?.add(URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com"))
        present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("error")
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble getting facebook shareing options to show up in xcode with swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892335/trouble-getting-facebook-shareing-options-to-show-up-in-xcode-with-swift-3)